# Making my mobile html fullscreen

Tags: html, css, mobile, webview

So I want to show [this](http://www.moma-soft.es/avalanche/forecast/) website in a webview (Android) and it works fine, but I don't know why it doesn't show up in full screen. I think there has to be something wrong with the css, but I am being unable to find it. This is a screenshot of what I see in my phone. I want the background to occupy the whole screen. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `background-size: 100% 100%;`? And what about `body {width: 100%; height:100%;}`?

Comment: yes, and it won't work. The answer by Oswaldo Acauan worked for the side paddings, but the bottom white strip is still there. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a padding in your "default.css". Remove the line 704.

```
@media all and (max-width: 960px){
    .center{
        width:auto;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want a full screen table, you need to add a `position: absolute` and `height: 100%` in our `.tablatop`.

```
.tablatop { //remember to put this style rule in your respective @media-query!!!
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solved the right and left side padding. The bottom white margin is still there :S

Comment: now it works perfect in the webview, but in my computer it looks bad. It doesn't matter, thank you so much!

Comment: you need to put your css for .tabletop just in the mobile @media rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is padding (`padding: 0 10px;` ) given to the div (in media query) that is why it is taking the space, remove it

```
@media (max-width: 960px)
.center {
padding: 0; 
width: auto;
}
```

Check the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about webview but try this:

```
body,html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    /*optional but incase it still doesn't work.*/
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    /*further optional still incase elements case overflows*/
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100;
    overflow:scroll;/*or hidden*/
```

To further target this device use a media query like so:

```
@media only screen and(max-device-width:(deviceWidthHere))and(max-device-height:(deviceHeightHere)){
    /*CSS here*/
    /*second 'and' clause is not necessarily necessary. lol*/
}
```